# (QUERY) - Selecting Rows From Specific Range

Tags: sql, t-sql

My task is to Return Orders between a range of @FirstOrderDate and @LastOrderDate, however only those rows that should belong on the page defined by @Page and @PageSize are returned.

For example, if there are 1,000 orders with an order date that falls between @FirstOrderDate and @LastOrderDate, and @PageSize is 100 with @Page as 1, then the first 100 of the 1,000 orders will be returned.  If @Page = 2, then the orders 101 - 200 will be returned, and so forth.

My attempt at the specific query using OFFSET:

```
    DECLARE 
    @FirstOrderDate DATE,
    @LastOrderDate DATE,
    @PageSize INT,
    @Page INT;

SELECT 
    O.OrderID,
    O.OrderDate,
    O.CustomerID,
    O.SalespersonPersonID
FROM Sales.Orders O 
WHERE O.OrderDate BETWEEN @FirstOrderDate AND @LastOrderDate
ORDER BY O.OrderDate
IF @Page = 1
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
ELSE
    OFFSET @Page * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

I am new to TSQL and I am not using the IF-Else properly. What I really need to do is return a range of rows using the @Page and @PageSize. I am having a hard time finding syntax for this, especially within an IF-Else or Case statement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IF`isn't valid here. Directly after the `ORDER BY` clause, try this:

```
OFFSET (@Page-1) * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```